# Cloning three other branches from a branch

Tags: linux, git, terminal, bitbucket

I have an empty branch named `result` which is empty. I need to clone from the `result` branch three other empty branches with names - `problem_1`, `problem_2` and `problem_3`. I need to paste the solutions in there and make three separate pull requests.

My question is how do I clone the `result` branch 3 times with the certain titles?  (with the terminal on linux)

Comment: You’ve used the word clone here. I don’t think you meant that but rather “create branch”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "result" branch, You can use git checkout -b [new-branch-name] to create a new branch based on "result" branch. Just do it 3 times and you get 3 branch.

Comment: Also good to know that you can do this from any branch with `git checkout -b <newBranchName> <sourceBranchOrCommit>`, or even `git branch <newBranchName> <sourceBranchOrCommit>` if you don't want to check it out immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To create branch from existing branch you can use the following steps

```
git push origin refs/heads/<source branch (result)>:refs/heads/<target branch (problem_1)>

git push origin refs/heads/<source branch (result)>:refs/heads/<target branch (problem_2)>

git push origin refs/heads/<source branch (result)>:refs/heads/<target branch (problem_3)>
```

This will create three branchs from result branch